# Excel Macro file size is too huge even though excel workbook is empty

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have created a simple macro that will import 3 xls files into macro and will compare the data and will create a output file with limited fields. But I see my macro file is **33,446 KB** even though the macro book sheets are empty.

is there any way to find out which line of code is taking time without doing step by step execution?

Input files & their file sizes

[image]

Excel macro file size

[image]

```
    Sub Macro_Step_1()
    Dim Wkb_1 As Workbook
    Dim Autosht As Worksheet, DLDataSht As Worksheet, SAPdataSht As Worksheet, Osht As Worksheet
    
    Set Wkb_1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set Autosht = Wkb_1.Sheets("Automation")
    Set DLDataSht = Wkb_1.Sheets("GLData")
    Set SAPdataSht = Wkb_1.Sheets("YFIINTDSRP")
    Set Osht = Wkb_1.Sheets("Output File")
    Set Tempsht = Wkb_1.Sheets("Temp")
    
    St = Now()
    
    Call TurnOffStuff
    
    wkbpath = Wkb_1.Path
    
    '***************************************************************************************************************************************
    FN = Dir(wkbpath & "\*.*")
    
            Do While FN <> ""
                        Debug.Print FN
                    If LCase(FN) Like LCase("*Report*.xls") Then
                        Compinfo = Compinfo & "|" & FN
                        Compinfo = IIf(Left(Compinfo, 1) = "|", Mid(Compinfo, 2, Len(Compinfo)), Compinfo)
                    ElseIf LCase(FN) Like LCase("*Raw*.xlsx") Then
                        LMPTinfo = FN
                        
                    End If
            FN = Dir()
            Loop
            
    '*******************************************Input Files missing alert******************************************************************
          If Compinfo = "" Or LMPTinfo = "" Then
            ReportName = ""
            ReportName = wkbpath & "\" & "Missing Input Files.txt"
            Open ReportName For Output As #1
            Close #1
            Exit Sub
            ReportName = ""
          End If
          
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        '//Clear Contents for Below mentioned Sheets Exluding Header
    
        Wkb_1.Activate
        
        DLDataSht.Rows("2:1000000").EntireRow.Clear
        
        SAPdataSht.Rows("2:1000000").EntireRow.Clear
        
        Tempsht.Rows("2:1000000").EntireRow.Clear
        
        Osht.Rows("1:1000000").EntireRow.Clear
    '*****************************Client Data***********************************************************************************************
     
     
    RptName = Split(Compinfo, "|")
     
         For Each Rsht In RptName
         
            Call Copy_Compinfo_Data("" & Rsht & "", "", "YFIINTDSRP")
        
         Next
    
    Call Copy_LMPTinfo_Data("" & LMPTinfo & "", "", "GLData")
    
    
    
    
    Call OutputMdl
    
    Tempsht.Rows("1:1000000").EntireRow.Clear
    
    '*********************************************************************************************************************************
    
    Call TurnONStuff
    
     '//Automation Run Time & Task Completetion Alert
        MsgBox "Process Completed Within " & Format(Now() - St, "HH:MM:SS"), vbInformation
    
    End Sub

Sub Copy_Compinfo_Data(IPWkb As String, IPSheet As String, DestSheetname As String)
Dim Del_1 As Long

Set Wkb_1 = ThisWorkbook
Set Tempsht = Wkb_1.Sheets("Temp")

    Tempsht.Rows("1:1000000").EntireRow.Clear

wkbpath = ThisWorkbook.Path

ShtInx = IIf(IPSheet = "", 1, IPSheet)


Set ws_master = Workbooks.Open(wkbpath & "\" & IPWkb)
    Shtname = ws_master.Sheets(1).Name
Set ws_Data = ws_master.Sheets(ShtInx)
    

Wkb_1.Activate
Set OrgFl = Wkb_1.Sheets(DestSheetname)

OrgFl.Select

ws_master.Sheets(1).Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ws_Data.Cells.Copy

Tempsht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False


ws_master.Activate

Windows(IPWkb).Close savechanges:=False


Wkb_1.Activate: Tempsht.Select
'HDRrow = 1

        Tempsht.Rows("1:7").EntireRow.Delete
        Tempsht.Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
        Tempsht.Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Delete
        Tempsht.Range("C:C").EntireColumn.Delete
        
        Tempsht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Tempsht.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A" & LR), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Tempsht.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:AB" & LR)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
        
        Wkb_1.Activate: Tempsht.Select
        
    If Tempsht.AutoFilterMode Then Tempsht.AutoFilterMode = False
        
    Tempsht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, LC)).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Company Code"
    If LR > 1 Then
        Tempsht.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LR, LC)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    End If
    Tempsht.ShowAllData
        
        
     '   For Del_1 = LR To 1 Step -1
        'Wkb_1.Activate: Tempsht.Select
            'Tempsht.Range(Cells(Del_1, 1), Cells(Del_1, LC)).Select
      '      Coun_ta = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Tempsht.Range(Cells(Del_1, 1), Cells(Del_1, LR)))
            
       '     If Tempsht.Range("B" & Del_1) = "" And Coun_ta <= 0 Then
                'Tempsht.Rows(Del_1).EntireRow.Select
                'Tempsht.Rows(Del_1).EntireRow.Delete
                
        '    ElseIf Tempsht.Range("A" & Del_1) = "*" Then
                'Tempsht.Rows(Del_1).EntireRow.Select
                'Tempsht.Rows(Del_1).EntireRow.Delete
         '   End If
            
        'Next
        
        Wkb_1.Activate: Tempsht.Select
    
    Tempsht.Cells(1, LC + 1) = "Report Name"
    'Tempsht.Range(Cells(2, LC), Cells(LR, LC)).Select
    Tempsht.Range(Cells(2, LC), Cells(LR, LC)) = IPWkb
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Tempsht.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LR, LC)).Copy
        
        Wkb_1.Activate
        
OrgFl.Select
OrgFl.Range("A" & LR + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Wkb_1.Activate: OrgFl.Select: OrgFl.Range("A1").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub

Sub Copy_LMPTinfo_Data(IPWkb As String, IPSheet As String, DestSheetname As String)
Set Wkb_1 = ThisWorkbook
Set Tempsht = Wkb_1.Sheets("Temp")
Set Osht = Wkb_1.Sheets("Output File")
Set DLDataSht = Wkb_1.Sheets("GLData")

    Tempsht.Rows("1:1000000").EntireRow.Clear
    DLDataSht.Rows("2:1000000").EntireRow.Clear
    
wkbpath = ThisWorkbook.Path


Set ws_master = Workbooks.Open(wkbpath & "\" & IPWkb)
    Shtname = ws_master.Sheets(1).Name

Sht_Count = ws_master.Sheets.Count


For ShtInx = 1 To Sht_Count
    Shtname = ws_master.Sheets(ShtInx).Name
Set ws_Data = ws_master.Sheets(ShtInx)
    
Wkb_1.Activate
Set OrgFl = Wkb_1.Sheets(DestSheetname)

OrgFl.Select
'OrgFl.Cells.Clear

ws_master.Sheets(Shtname).Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ws_Data.Cells.Copy

Tempsht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Tempsht.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Delete


        Tempsht.Columns("D:D").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
        Tempsht.Columns("F:F").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
        Tempsht.Columns("J:J").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("J1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
        Tempsht.Columns("M:M").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("M1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
        Tempsht.Columns("Q:Q").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Q1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        
        Tempsht.Columns("U:U").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("U1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


        Tempsht.Columns("G:H").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
        TEmpLastRow = Tempsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
  
        Tempsht.Columns("A").Insert: Tempsht.Range("A1") = "Month"
        Wkb_1.Activate: Tempsht.Select
        Tempsht.Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(TEmpLastRow, "A")) = Shtname & "'" & Format(Now(), "YY")
        
        Wkb_1.Activate: Tempsht.Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Tempsht.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LR, LC)).Copy
        Wkb_1.Activate
        DLDataSht.Select
              LastRow = DLDataSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        DLDataSht.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
ws_master.Activate

Next

Windows(IPWkb).Close savechanges:=False


End Sub

Sub OutputMdl()
Set Wkb_1 = ThisWorkbook
Set Autosht = Wkb_1.Sheets("Automation")
Set DLDataSht = Wkb_1.Sheets("GLData")
Set SAPdataSht = Wkb_1.Sheets("YFIINTDSRP")
Set Osht = Wkb_1.Sheets("Output File")
Set Tempsht = Wkb_1.Sheets("Temp")

Osht.Rows("1:1000000").EntireRow.Clear

Wkb_1.Activate: Osht.Select

        Wkb_1.Activate: DLDataSht.Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        DLDataSht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, LC)).Copy
        Wkb_1.Activate
        Osht.Select

        Osht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

   ' Osht.Range("O:O").EntireColumn.Delete
    Osht.Range("R:V").EntireColumn.Delete
    
    Osht.Range("C:C").EntireColumn.Delete
    
    Osht.Columns("F:F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Osht.Range("F1") = "Section"
    Osht.Range("F2:F" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G2,Mapping!A:B,2,0)"
    
    Osht.Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Osht.Range("J1") = "Expense G/L"
    Osht.Range("J2:J" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G2,Mapping!A:B,2,0)"
    
    Osht.Columns("P:V").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Osht.Range("P1") = "Vendor Code"
    Osht.Range("P2:P" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G2,YFIINTDSRP!H:J,3,0)"
    
    Osht.Range("Q1") = "Vendor Name"
    Osht.Range("Q2:Q" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G2,YFIINTDSRP!H:K,4,0)"
    
    Osht.Range("R1") = "Vendor PAN"
    Osht.Range("R2:R" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G2,YFIINTDSRP!H:L,5,0)"
    
    Osht.Range("T2:T" & LR).Formula = "=LEFT(S2,4)"
    
    Osht.Range("U2:U" & LR).Formula = "=RIGHT(U2,1)"
    
    Osht.Range("V1") = "WHT Base Amount"
    
    Osht.Range("W1") = "Amount in local curre ncy As per GL"
    
    Osht.Range("Y1") = "Return TDS"
    Osht.Range("Z1") = "Return rateS"
    
    Osht.Range("Z2:Z" & LR).Formula = "=Y2/W2*100"
    
    Osht.Range("AA1") = "RPU Base"
    Osht.Range("AA2:AA" & LR).Formula = "=-W2"
    
    Osht.Range("AB1") = "RPU TDS"
    Osht.Range("AB2:AB" & LR).Formula = "=-Y2"
    
    'Osht.Range("R1") = "Vendor PAN"
    'Osht.Range("R2:R" & LR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(H2,YFIINTDSRP!H:L,5,0)"
    
    Osht.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Osht.Range("A1") = "Working Remark"
    
    
    
    Osht.Range("AE1") = "Certifiacte"
    Osht.Range("AF1") = "Reason"
    Osht.Range("AG1") = "BSRCode"
    Osht.Range("AH1") = "Tender Date"
    Osht.Range("AI1") = "Challan Sn"
    Osht.Range("AJ1") = "SN"
    
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------
    '//Creating Output file
        Path = ThisWorkbook.Path
        
        Dim OWkb As Workbook
    
         Set OWkb = Workbooks.Add
        
        File_Name = Autosht.Range("D8")
        
        Wkb_1.Sheets("Output File").Copy OWkb.Sheets(OWkb.Sheets.Count)

        OWkb.SaveAs Filename:=Path & "\" & File_Name, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        
        OWkb.Activate: OWkb.Sheets("Output File").Range("A1").Select: OWkb.Save: Windows(File_Name).Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the size of the macro work look causing a specific problem? Regardless, consider setting the workbook up as an add in and combining your files in a new workbook.

Comment: How sure are you that the directory you're processing has exactly those 3 files that match `"*Report*.xls"` and no more?

Comment: `ws_Data.Cells.Copy` - you are copying the entire sheet here: it would be tidier to copy only the occupied cells.  Find the last-used row and column and only copy up to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Cleaning process for each sheet.

From the Last Edited Column till the End column (Towards Right).Select and Delete  all columns (Ctrl + '-')
From the Last Edited Row till the End Row (Towards Bottom).Select and Delete  all rows (Ctrl + '-')

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 'Macro file size':  No answer for this other than to suggest:

1. Export the modules from the 'big' macro workbook
2. Create a brand new workbook
3. Import the files from step 1 into the new workbook.

The new workbook will be smaller.  If it grows every time you run your code - then that's where you can start to figure out the problem.  Run just parts of the code until you can detect what code is changing the file size.

Your next question is how to find slow or lengthy operations.  This can be done with code like:

```
Dim timeDuration As Variant
Dim timeStart As Variant
Dim timeEnd As Varient

timeStart = Timer

'Call a function or subroutine

timeEnd = Timer

Debug.Print "<Method Name> duration: " & CStr(timeEnd - timeStart)
```

Evaluate the results in the `Immediate` window

Or, you can put the code within each method and grab `timeStart` at the top of the method and `timeEnd` at the bottom.

It is helpful here is to have code that is grouped into focused methods that the above code can surround.  The provided code has 4 methods...so that would be the first set of results to look at - and then proceed from there.

Evaluating the code was harder than it needed to be due to coding style.  Some suggestions for you to consider:

**Option Explicit**

There are few VBA guidelines that fall under the category of *always*, but this is one of them:

**Always** declare `Option Explicit` at the top of any module you create in VBA.  `Option Explicit` forces the developer to explicitly declare all variables, constants, and fields before using them within a module.

Declaring `Option Explicit` at the top of the provided code and invoking 'Debug -> Compile VBA Project'  will identify 44 local variables that are used, but never declared and two subroutines that prevent the posted code from compiling (I assume the subroutines exist in another module...just not the one posted).

(Suggestion) The Visual Basice Editor (VBE) will automatically place `Option Explicit` at the top of new modules by checking 'Tools -> Options... ->  Require Variable Declaration'.

**Use Meaningful Names**

All developers spend far more time reading code that writing it.  Consequently, it is exceedingly important that code has variable names that are easily interpreted as to content and functionality.  While actively writing code, it is easy to know/remember what variables like `LR` and/or `LC` *mean*.  Step away from the code for 24 hours (or read it for the first time on an SO question)...and it's not.

The standard joke is: *There are 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors.*  That 'naming things' makes the list underscores both its importance (and difficulty).  Long names will not slow down your code...use longer/descriptive names to make your life easier.

(Suggestion)Use names that are *at least* three characters but preferably full words that convey some meaning.  Consider the name from the perspective of a first-time reviewer.

**Manage variable Scope**

This is related to using `Option Explicit`.  There are 3 variable scopes in VBA: `Global`, `Module`, and `Local`.  Some variables names in this code are repeated/used in several subroutines.  These variables should be declared explicitly at the top of the module (Module Scope).

Look at how variable `Wkb_1` is used.  It is declared in `Macro_Step_1` but used (without a declaration) in the next 3 subroutines.  It is a `Workbook` object in the `Macro_Step_1` (by declaration), but is a `Variant` in all subsequent uses because it is not explicitly declared.  Further, it is assigned the Global `ThisWorkbook` object.  `ThisWorkbook` should be used directly and `Wkb_1` can be deleted.  And, relating back to 'Use Meaningful Names', using `Wkb_1` obscures the fact (further down the procedure) that it represents the `ThisWorkbook` object.  `wkbpath = ThisWorkbook.Path` is much more clear than `wkbpath = Wkb_1.Path`.

(Suggestion) Review all your variables' scope and declare them in the appropriate locations.

**Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)**

If you find yourself with a workflow of 'Copy - Paste - change a string', it is time to consider how to capture the code in a procedure.  This will make your code easier to read, understand, and sometimes...faster depending on the operations involved.

The code

```
Tempsht.Columns("D:D").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Was created using the above workflow 6 times.  The entire wall of copied code can be replaced with:

```
    GiveThisOperationAName "D", "F", "J", "M", "Q", "U"
```

Where `GiveThisOperationAName` is:

```
Private Sub GiveThisOperationAName(ParamArray columnLetters() As Variant)
    
    Dim tempWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set tempWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
    
    Dim columnLetter As Variant
    For Each columnLetter In columnLetters
        tempWorksheet.Columns(columnLetter & ":" & columnLetter).TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range(columnLetter & "1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Next
End Sub
```

(Suggestion) There are other areas of opportunity like this.  Removing duplication will make your code easier to read/understand, easier to maintain/modify, and easier to instrument for performance testing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, I advanced the code line by line (using F8) until I found the exact line that the scroll bar increased in size, I found out it was a line where I was formatting an entire column, I guess storing the format information in each cell, in your case I suspect the line `Tempsht.Columns("G:H").NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"`.

**My recommendations:**

- use CTRL + END to check the last cell with data in your spreadsheet;
- delete all rows below your data, save and close the workbook, you should notice a smaller file size, reopen and use CTRL + END again, pay attention to the scrollbar;
- run the macro using F8 and pay attention to the scrollbar again;
- do entire column formatting in the worksheet instead of the code, if you have to do it in the code, do it only for the written data.

**PS:** *I realize it's too late to help, but maybe this will help others searching google with the same problem, like me.*